# how do i link my .env file to my html file and use it in a script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, environment-variables

I'm trying to make a simple login page on my dashboard so only people with an admin key can view it. I have the js coding for the login page in a script tag in the HTML, and so I need to link the .env file to hide the admin key. How exactly would I do that?

Here is my js coding for it:

```
<script>
function checkPswd() {
  var confirmPassword = "pswd";
  var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
  if (password == confirmPassword) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("result").style.padding = "25px";
    document.getElementById("hiddenContent").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    alert("Passwords do not match.");
  }
}
```

The "confirmPassword" I wanna replace with the admin key.

Answer (score 1):

The browser belongs to and works for the user. You cannot give something to the browser while keeping it a secret from the user.

If you want to do authentication then you need to do it with *server side* code. You can't ask the user's browser to make sure that the user is who they say they are. The browser doesn't work for you.

A `.env` file is used to keep secrets and data that varies between environments out of a code repository (e.g. a git repository) so that the passwords and configuration for a specific environment aren't distributed to everywhere that the software is installed. It isn't a way to give information to the browser without giving it to the user.

Comment: I know that... and i wanna keep the admin key a secret and use it as a way for my staff to get to the dashboard... Is that not possible?

Comment: It’s possible if you do the authentication server-side, as I said.

Answer (score -1):

You can like the environment variables those exists in .env file by wraps the key of the secret between percentage symbol.

in .env file
MY_SECRET=******

in html file
%MY_SECRET%